# Gameplaying on a university network where ports are blocked

Tags: router, port-forwarding, gaming, proxy-server

I live and work on a large university where maybe 18,000 people are using the network at any given time, so the network engineers have setup a web proxy we must log into to access the internet. It appears that 2 new games I just purchased needs specific ports to be used in MMOs. I am certain that the university will not open these ports just for me to use my PlayStation. Is there anyway I can use port forwarding on my in-home router which is connected to the university network that will allow these games to work?

Thanks.
Cole

Comment: Your traffic will still need to go through the university network to get to the Internet, so it will still need to follow the university network rules.

Comment: As long as the traffic follows the network rules, perhaps a tunnel / VPN arrangement would be helpful?

Comment: Your questions seems not to be about game-playing, but rather about hosting Servers for those games. Please be more precise and maybe tell us which games we are talking about

Answer (score 1):

> Is there anyway I can use port forwarding on my in-home router

You clearly don't understand port forwarding.  You may be able to do what you want to do, but not the way you're trying to do it.  The name of the technology, "port forwarding", sounds like roughly what you're trying to accomplish.

Port forwarding typically has to do with the router *receiving* traffic from the Internet, on a specific port (typically TCP or UDP, although I know at least SCTP also uses ports), and then your router knows what internal device the traffic should be sent to.  For instance, if your router receives traffic on TCP port 80, you want the traffic to go to the computer that is running a web server, not to your Playstation that will ignore the web traffic.

You could accomplish your goal by using a tunnel to an external site.  VPN traffic tends to use tunnels (although the P in VPN refers to Private, as VPNs include encryption, which may be more than what you need).  Basically, you need to find a way to get the traffic routed in both directions.  This sounds possible as long as the equipment you use, such as the university, doesn't prevent this.  Even if the only traffic allowed is a specific protocol, like web traffic, your desired communications can travel over such a protocol.  (e.g., running TCP over ICMP.)  A performance hit may be unavoidable.

Your best bet will be to get the ports opened, so traffic goes right where it is supposed to.

> I am certain that the university will not open these ports just for me to use my PlayStation.

Okay.  But since you live on campus, you could ask them to port the ports just for you to use personally.  As you live on campus, it may be entirely reasonable for them to permit the communications just to support your personal use.

Note that I'm assuming that we're talking about traffic initiated with outbound connections.  You'll probably also want to get a static IP address (at least a private one, probably starting with 10. or 192.168. or 172.16. through 172.31., or fd).  They wouldn't need to document this as "workaround for Playstation".  They could document this as "Professor M's personal router", and it wouldn't look very silly in their firewall rules.

Basically, just avoid the word Playstation, and say that you have some personal equipment that you want to use, and you want to use the university network since you live on campus.

You might benefit from creating an anonymous account (you probably really should have done so for this question), and creating a new question, and getting specific (what MMO, what ports, does that need to be incoming or outgoing traffic), and some less generalized advice may be able to be provided.